# Ajax call doesn't hit the Server and returns HTML - ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my server side code:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool mymethod()
{
   bool success = false;
   return success;
}
```

and this is the Ajax request I'm trying to make:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'mymethod',
    type:'POST',
    data:{},
    success:function(data){console.log(data);},
    error:function(data){console.log(data);},
})
```

Every time I make the request, it returns the complete HTML page (view) and never hits the Server method. Please help.

Comment: Check the url in the network tab for ajax call. Also specify `dataType ` and `contentType` for ajax call.

Comment: You need to make the url relative.. right now it's probably returning the HTML of your browsers error page because it can't find the website "mymethod".

Comment: try using this pattern in your URL  `/Home(controller name)/mymethod (action name)`

Comment: I think URL which is hit is not well formed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Simon Whitehead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517578/simon-whitehead) for pointing out. I made the path relative and it worked:

```
$.ajax({
url:'../mymethod',
type:'POST',
data:{},
success:function(data){console.log(data);},
error:function(data){console.log(data);},
})
```

Thanks again :)